# Python substring square parenthesis don't accept variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I'm trying to run a script that takes a long series of numbers and checks them 4 at a time, so I'm using a `for in range(0, len(stringOfDigits), 4):` checking the string of numbers using the variable of the loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(stringOfDigits), 4):
    currFour = stringOfDigits[i:4]
    print("Current 4 being checked are")
    print(currFour)
```

But if I try to run it, it just pastes empty rows and exit the script like it's done.

What's the problem? Do strings accept variables when substringing? If not, what can I do to achieve the result I want?

Comment: Do `currFour = digits[i:i+4]`.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev Any particular reason for that? I mean, isn't it technically the same? Why you need to use the variable for both of the range limits?

Comment: No, they aren't same. If you want to check `i`th position to the next four positions, you need `digits[i:i+4]`, but if you need to check `i`th position to only the `4`th item of `digits`, then you need `digits[i:4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following inside loop:

```
currFour = stringOfDigits[i:i+4]
```

instead of:

```
currFour = stringOfDigits[i:4]
```

With `currFour = stringOfDigits[i:4]`, first loop works, but successive loopings fail. This is because: One case in the second iteration when `i` becomes 4, `stringOfDigits[i:4]` -> `stringOfDigits[4:4]` (where you ideally needed  a slice of `[4:8]`) which returns empty string and so on for remaining loopings.

Comment: Any particular reason for that? I mean, isn't it technically the same? Why you need to use the variable for both of the range limits?

Comment: 'cause u need to make slicing relatively current position of `i`, but not absolute.